# Cant load CSS with Docker installation on Superset

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I installed superset following these steps using Docker but when I go to http://localhost:8088/superset there is no CSS. Furthermore, every time I try to create a chart I get sent back to the main page. Like, if I hit http://localhost:8088/chart/add I get the same static interface of http://localhost:8088/superset

I am trying to install on a MacBookPro 2018.

Link to installation steps I followed
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docs/installation.rst#user-content-start-with-docker

Code I used

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/

cd incubator-superset/contrib/docker

docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh

docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed Apache Superset, docker version and I faced the similar issue. When I logged into the superset container by running `docker exec` I found that webpack.js was taking time to compile source. Once done it loaded perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes time to build the `superset_node` package, which is responsible for compiling the UI components. In order to force-build them without waiting,

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```